# Recursive function to loop an object and set value, with an array of nested properties to join objects

Tags: javascript, json, function, recursion

I have multiple json5 files that I need to join in one object.

Example the main object that other files will join to:
`/equations/mass-energy-equivalence.json5`

```js
{
    name: 'Mass-energy equivalence',
    expression: 'E=mc^{2}',
    expressionIntern: '\\mag{E}=\\mag{m}\\const{c}^{2}',
    description: '...',
    categories: ['physics'],
    units: [
        'joule'
    ],
    constants: [
        'speed-of-light'
    ],
    magnitudes: [
        'energy', 'mass'
    ],
    values: [
        { value: 1000, units: ['joule'] }
    ]
}
```

`/magnitudes/energy.json5`

```js
{ name: 'Energy', symbol: 'E', slug: 'energy', units: ['joule'],  description: '', ... }
```

So Magnitudes have units, i have to join `units/joule` with `magnitudes/energy` and finally to the first object.
`/units/joule.json5`

```js
{ name: 'Joule', symbol: 'J', slug: 'joule', description: '', ... }
```

And so on.

I need to join: categories, units, constants and mangitudes. Just like MySQL join. Also magnitudes has units so they have to be joined too.
So I'm trying to do a function that gets an array of nested properties like this:

**This is the input to the function:**

```js
const nestedProperties = [
    'categories.slug',
    'constants.slug.units.slug',
    'magnitudes.slug',
    'units.slug',
    'variables.slug.units.slug',
    'values.units.slug'
];
```

Needs to do this for all the `nestedProperties`. **The final object will be the output**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yat2V.jpg

I have a function that gets the data `await getData()` so I need this recursive function that will set `data.categories = await getData('categories', slug: 'physics')`

My idea is something like this... yet not finished.

```js
getAllData(object, nestedProperties) {
    nestedProperties.forEach(async (item) => {
        const parts = item.split('.');
        const size = parts.length;
        // We need at least two parts to get the data.
        if(size === 0) console.error('Invalid Path');
        // Size is even so is a multiple of 2
        // ex. categories.slug
        if(size % 2 === 0) {
            for(let i = 0; i < size - 2; i += 2) {
                // path.property -> categories.slug
                if(i == 0) {
                    let path = parts[i];
                    let property = parts[i + 1];
                    // If the path is in the data and is an array with items
                    // ex. data[categories]
                    if(Array.isArray(data[path]) && data[path].length > 0) {
                        // Iterate
                        for(let i = 0; i < data[path].length; i++) {
                            // path => 'categories',
                            // data[path] => 'physics'
                            data[path] = getData(path, data[path]);
                            // Recursive data[path] = getAllData(path, data[path])
                            
                        }
                    } else {
                        data[path] = getAllData(path, data[path])
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Is odd so we need to do it a bit different
            // ex. 'values.units.slug'
        }
    }
}
```

Been trying a lot but not success to get to the 2 or 3 nested property :[
Thanks a lot.

Comment: clarify how `nestedProperties` is made

Comment: Example: 'categories.slug' categories is the path where file is and slug is the property for how I get the file.

So that represents this: `categories/physics.json5` from:
```javascript
{
    name: 'Mass-energy equivalence',
    ...
    categories: ['physics'],
```
It can be either a string or an array. It's like a foreign key of mysql

Comment: I think you're missing some information here.  Where does `"variables"` get used?  What are `"symbol"`, `"description"`, and `"type"` and where do they come from?  Is your first JSON sample the input and your last one the output?  How does `"constants.slug.units.slug"` get represented in the sample output?

Comment: Also, `getData('categories', slug: 'physics')` is not legal syntax.  Did you mean something like `getData('categories', {slug: 'physics'})` (note the curly braces.)  Or is it supposed to be something different?

Comment: I see. There are files for `categories/physics.json5` (categories.slug), `constants/speed-of-light.json5` (constants.slug), `units/a.json5, b.json5, etc..`, (units.slug). So the nestedProperties array represents how and from where I get the other files to be join by the first (input) .The first is the object that will get all the data from other json files, and yes, the last is the otuput, how the first json will look with all the other json files joined.

Comment: Yes I know,  for getData() the correct way is getData('categories', 'physics') I was trying to refer to the nestedProperties. This array represents the foreing jsons `categories.slug` -> `'categories', 'physics'`, constants  has also units so that's why `constants.slug.units.slug` means that `'units', 'a'` will join with `'constants', 'speed-of-light'` and that will join the `mass-energy-equivalence` (the first json). Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: I think it would help to have samples of these secondary calls.  They don't have to be complete, but for instance does `categories/physics.json5` have a property called `slug`?  Does it have one called `description`?

Comment: I'm also still unclear what you mean by "`'units', 'a'` will join with `'constants', 'speed-of-light'`"  Perhaps stepping through the calls you expect to make to `getData` would make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, all json files have key `slug` and `description`, I'll try to make a better function and I'll update it. 'units', 'a' was just for example that some files need to join with other files and then to the first file.

Comment: I was suggesting that you supply more data, not more code.  Both can be helpful, of course.  But so far it's simply not clear where your output is supposed to be coming from...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237734/discussion-between-derian-andre-and-scott-sauyet).

Comment: This question is not very clear. What is your input(s) and what is your expected output?

Comment: The input will be `object, nestedProperties`, object in this case is `mass-energy-equivalence.json5` and the `nestedProperties` array the output is the final object: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yat2V.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't have time right now to write up a more complete explanation of this, so I'll be brief.  If I find time tomorrow, I'll add more explanation.  It's not complete, and doesn't handle your `'constants.slug.units.slug'`, so it might really be way off.  (I actually simply remove the `slug` nodes, as I don't make sense of them.)

`getData` is just a dummy, meant to allow us to run something like your `getData` above.  (Is this the equivalent of [`$content` from your code](https://github.com/Equreka/Equreka/blob/main/utils/data.js#L1)?).

**`last`** is a trivial helper getting the last element of an array.

**`getPath`** takes a path such as `['foo', 1' 'bar']` and an object such as `{foo: [{bar: 1, baz: 2}, {bar: 3, baz: 4}], qux: 5}` and returns `3`, the value of the `bar` property of the element at index `1` of the `foo` property of our object.

**`setPath`** simply reverses this:

```js
setPath (['foo', 1, 'bar']) (42) ({foo: [{bar: 1, baz: 2}, {bar: 3, baz: 4}], qux: 5})
//=> {foo: [{bar: 1, baz: 2}, {bar: 42, baz: 4}], qux: 5}
```

**`fullPaths`** is more complex.  It deals with the fact that you have fields that might be arrays or might be scalar values.  It takes a path such as ['magnitudes'] and your initial data and finds the paths in the format required by `getPath` and `setPath`.  Thus

```js
fullPaths (['magnitudes']) (rawData) //=> [["magnitudes", 0], ["magnitudes", 1]]
```

which in turn point to `'energy'` and `'mass'`, respectively.

With these helpers in place, we can write **`getAllData`**.

That uses `fullPaths` after taking your `nestedProperties` and turning them to arrays, removing the `'slug'` substrings.  With these results, we can dig into, say `values.units.slug` to get `['values', 0, 'units', 0]`, which maps to `'joules'`, and using `'units'` and `'joules'` we call `getData`.

After the Promises return resolve, we can fold over the results, calling such things as `setPath (['values', 0, 'units', 0], promiseResult, accumulator)`.  We return the result of that fold.

I don't know if I'll have much time to come back to this, but in case I do, I'd love to hear how close this is to your requirements.  It's not clear to me for instance if you need to run those same `getAllData` over each result returned from `getData`, and if you do, whether the same `nestedProperties` are to be used for them.

I also don't know how to deal with the `constants.slug.units.slug`, as our constants are string values and don't have units.

```js
const last = (xs) => 
  xs [xs .length - 1]

const getPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? o : getPath (ps) (o && o[p])

const setPath = ([p, ...ps]) => (v) => (o) =>
  p == undefined ? v : Object .assign (
    Array .isArray (o) || Number .isInteger (p) ? [] : {},
    {...o, [p]: setPath (ps) (v) ((o || {}) [p])}
  )

const fullPaths = ([p, ...ps]) => (o) => 
  p == undefined 
    ? [[]]
  : Array .isArray (o)
     ? o .flatMap ((x, i) => fullPaths (ps) (x [p]) .map (ns => [p, i, ...ns]))
  : Object (o) === o
     ? p in o
       ? Array .isArray (o [p])
         ? o [p] .map ((x, i) => fullPaths (ps) (x) .flatMap ((x) => [p, i, ...x]))
         : fullPaths (ps) (o [p]) .map (x => [p, ...x])
     : []
  : [[p]]

const getAllData = (
  rawData, 
  nestedProperties, 
  paths = nestedProperties .map (s => s.split ('.')) 
                           .map (a => a.filter (s => s !== 'slug'))
                           .flatMap (p => fullPaths (p) (rawData))
) => 
  Promise .all (
    paths .map (
      p => getData (
        last (p .filter (s => String (s) === s)), 
        getPath (p) (rawData)
      )
    )
  ) .then (res => res .reduce (
    (a, r, i) => setPath (paths[i]) (r) (a), 
    rawData 
  ))

const rawData = {name: 'Mass-energy equivalence', expression: 'E=mc^{2}', expressionIntern: '\\mag{E}=\\mag{m}\\const{c}^{2}', description: '...', categories: ['physics'], units: ['joule'], constants: ['speed-of-light'],  magnitudes: ['energy', 'mass'], values: [{value: 1000, units: ['joule']}]}
const nestedProperties = ['categories.slug',   /*'constants.slug.units.slug',*/ 'magnitudes.slug', 'units.slug', 'variables.slug.units.slug', 'values.units.slug']

getAllData (rawData, nestedProperties )
  .then ((r) => console .log(JSON.stringify(r, null, 4)))
  .catch (console .warn)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script> <!-- Dummy version of getData -->
const getData = ((data) => async (group, value) => group in data && value in data [group] ? Promise .resolve (data [group] [value]) : Promise .reject (`Cannot find ${group}/${value}`))({categories: {physics: {id: 2, name: "Physics", description: "Physics (from Ancient Greek: φυσική (ἐπιστήμη), romanized: physikḗ (epistḗmē), lit. 'knowledge of nature', from φύσις phýsis 'nature') is the natural science that studies matter, its motion and behavior through space and time, and the related entities of energy and force. Physics is one of the most fundamental scientific disciplines, and its main goal is to understand how the universe behaves."}, chemistry: {id: 3, name: "Chemistry", description: "Chemistry is the scientific discipline involved with elements and compounds composed of atoms, molecules and ions: their composition, structure, properties, behavior and the changes they undergo during a reaction with other substances."}}, units: {joule: {name: "Joule", symbol: {text: "J", html: "J", tex: "J"}, type: "si", categories: ["physics"], units: ["joule-per-kelvin", "joule-second"], description: "The joule (/dʒaʊl,  dʒuːl/ jowl,  jool) is a derived unit of energy in the International System of Units. It is equal to the energy transferred to (or work done on) an object when a force of one newton acts on that object in the direction of the force's motion through a distance of one metre (1 newton metre or $N⋅m$). It is also the energy dissipated as heat when an electric current of one ampere passes through a resistance of one ohm for one second. It is named after the English physicist James Prescott Joule (1818–1889)."}}, magnitudes: {energy: {name: 'Energy', symbol: {text: 'E', html: 'E', tex: 'E',}, categories: ['physics'], description: 'In physics, energy is the quantitative property that must be transferred to an object in order to perform work on, or to heat, the object. Energy is a conserved quantity; the law of conservation of energy states that energy can be converted in form, but not created or destroyed. The SI unit of energy is the joule, which is the energy transferred to an object by the work of moving it a distance of 1 metre against a force of 1 newton.', baseUnit: 'joule', units: ['joule']}, mass: {name: "Mass", symbol: {text: "m", html: "m", tex: "m"}, categories: ["physics"], description: "Property of matter to resist changes of the state of motion and to attract other bodies", baseUnit: "kilogram", units: ["tonne", "kilogram", "gram", "milligram", "microgram", "long-ton", "short-ton", "stone", "pound", "ounce"]}}, constants: {'speed-of-light': {name: "Speed of light in vacuum", symbol: {text: "c", html: "c", tex: "c"}, description: "The speed of light in vacuum, commonly denoted $c$, is a universal physical constant important in many areas of physics. Its exact value is defined as $299, 792, 458$ $m/s$ (approximately $300, 000$ $km/s$,  or $18, 6000$ $mi/s$). It is exact because, by international agreement, a metre is defined as the length of the path travelled by light in vacuum during a time interval of $\\frac{1}{299, 792, 458}$ second. According to special relativity, $c$ is the upper limit for the speed at which conventional matter, energy or any information can travel through coordinate space.", categories: ["universal", "physics"], units: ["metre-per-second"], values: [{value: 299792458, units: "metre-per-second", exact: false, base: false}, {value: 3e8, units: "metre-per-second", exact: false}]}}})
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Scott!, I really appreciate this.
Yes, I use `$content()` to get the data and I'll replace `getData()` with it.
Regarding re-using `getAllData` for the results, yes, I have to use that same function again as the results also have `nestedProperties` as `categories` and `units`.
I will analyze your code and do some testing over the course of this week and I'll report back!

Comment: More information about [`getPath`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20getPath) and [`setPath`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1243641%20setPath) can be found in other answers of mine.  `last` is trivial.  `getData` is uninteresing.  The real work is in `findPaths` and of course `getAllData`.

Comment: And if you want to play with it in the REPL where I built it, it's at http://link.sauyet.com/32.